# (Ubuntu 15.10 64 Bit) Similar errors when running wine/steam/aapt - newline unexpected, expecting ")"

Tags: bash, wine, android, steam, playonlinux

I'm getting some similar errors while running aapt from Android-Studio,
Running wine via playonlinux (haven't tried normal wine yet) or when trying to install steam. Perhaps with other programs as well, though I haven't tested them all.

After a bit of googling I haven't found a viable solution.

Here's an example from aapt in Android-Studio:

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1508687752): /home/xxx/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: 2: /home/xxx/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")
```

The errors in wine and steam are similar, it's always syntax error and that it's expecting ")" or that "(" is unexpected.

I've also tested it with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test'
array=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo ${array[*]}
```

which gives me the same error when running with sh.
When I'm running it with bash or "./" it works fine.

What's the cause of this problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Here's the result from the script:
testscript.sh: 4: testscript.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Don't run scripts with the wrong interpreter? See [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: I'm starting the studio.sh from Android-Studio via ./studio.sh while I'm in the folder of it and it's still not working... 
Do I have to reconfigure anything for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so many people don't know this, but by default Ubuntu links `/bin/sh` to `dash`, not `bash`. You can check this with the following:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

The `dash` shell does not support arrays as `bash` does as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571).

You can check what shell you currently have open with:

```
echo "$SHELL"
```

That said, it's very odd that pre-packaged programs would be encountering that error. I would expect them to already start with `#!/bin/bash` if they needed it.

You can edit the scripts in question to include `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

If a script does not have a "shebang" line (the `#!` and etc. at the top) then the current shell is the default for using `./` for execution. You can change your login shell with `chsh` followed by your password when prompted and `/bin/bash` when prompted. You will have to relog.

If that doesn't help, you could also change the symlink (this probably won't break anything, but YMMV):

```
sudo rm /bin/sh
sudo ln -s bash /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried your solution and it seems to have done something, though now I get:
"/home/xxx/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: Couldn't execute the file.", [translated from german], when running aapt.
Any other clue what I could do? I changed the symlink as well to bash.

Comment: Does explicitly running `/bin/bash studio.sh` work?